# Need cross-platform GUI toolkit with OpenGL support

Tags: c++, user-interface

I need a cross-platform GUI toolkit with OpenGL support. I also need to be able to draw on a canvas or panel from an image buffer. The candidates I've chosen so far are FLTK (it can do OpenGL windows -- I don't know about canvases), Qt, and wxWidgets.

Any idea which would be the best?

Thanks!

Comment: You should review your question. The way it is now, it calls for subjective opinions, and that is against SO policy. Asking for strengths or weaknesses would be slightly more objective.

Answer (score 5):

I would say Qt. But that might be argumentative question...

Answer (score 1):

Hey Deep,  XVT support openGL.  It's a GUI cross-platform toolkit for C and C++  www.xvt.com

Answer (score 0):

For simple things I would suggest GLUT or something similar. But for anything above a simple window into which you render some OpenGL, I strongly recommend Qt. But as tibur said, its probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Ecere SDK](http://ecere.com/wiki#Ecere_SDK). It's a feature rich cross-platform GUI toolkit, and it supports a variety of graphics driver (e.g. GDI, X11, OpenGL, Direct3D). It has a built-in 3D engine, but you can mix it with your own OpenGL code as well, there are samples showing you how to do just that. It was originally designed as a GUI system for in-game menus, so it supports full screen mdoe as well as windowed mode, but is now a general purpose SDK.